# Ant overwritting custom manifest file

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am creating a jar with Ant that also uses a custom manifest file.  The build.xml file builds everything properly.  However, when I check the manifest file in the jar, my properties are not there.  It looks like it is being replaced with the default MANIFEST.MF file built by Ant.  My build file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<property name="src" location="src" />
<property name="build" location="build" />
<property name="dist" location="dist" />

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}" />
    <delete dir="${dist}" />
</target>

<target name="main" depends="compile, dist, build">
    <echo>
        Building the .jar file.
    </echo>
</target>

<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}/META-INF" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="build">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" />
    <manifest file="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="MyGame.jar" />
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="game.Game"/>    
    </manifest>

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyGame.jar" basedir="${build}" />

</target>
```

What do I have to change to specify the custom manifest instead of the default Ant MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: Putting more attributes in the <manifest> tag should help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the jar ant task has a manifest attribute where you can specify the actual file to use. In this case you'd reference the file you created with the manifest task

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" />

    <manifest file="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="MyGame.jar" />
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="game.Game"/>  
    </manifest>

    <jar manifest="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyGame.jar" basedir="${build}" />

</target>
```

Comment: I was missing the "manifest" attribute when defining the jar.  Thanks!

Comment: The key point is that you can't just jar up a MANIFEST.MF file like the other files, it WILL be ignored by ant. Instead you 
HAVE to use the 'manifest' attribute or the nested <manifest> element directly.