# Java compilation error: could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java, compilation

I've tried many configurations and parameter settings, but keep getting `Error: Could not find or load main class Main` error.

Most of the code I've copied from other SO questions and the documentation of the ant project, and I don't really see where the issue lies. Perhaps someone can see what I'm overlooking.

**Directory structure**

```
├───build
│   ├───com
│   │   └───cfsware
│   │       └───osco
│   │           └───test
│   └───META-INF
├───dist
│   └───lib
└───src
    └───com
        └───cfsware
            └───osco
                └───test
```

**build.properties**

```
main.dir=. 
src.dir=${main.dir}/src 
build.dir=build 
classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes 
jar=${build.dir}/test.jar 
javadoc.dir=${build.dir}/javadoc 
build.sysclasspath=ignore 
# E.g.: cp=lib/x.jar:lib/y.jar 
cp= 
extra.run.cp= 
main.class=com.cfsware.osco.test.Main 
run.cp=${cp}:${classes.dir}:${extra.run.cp} 
debug=true 
deprecation=false 
nbjdk.home=${basedir}/../../..
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project name="ant" default="dist" basedir="."> 
<description>ant build file</description> 
<property name="src" location="src"/> 
<property name="build" location="build"/> 
<property name="dist" location="dist"/> 
<target name="init"><tstamp/><mkdir dir="${build}"/></target> 
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source"><javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/></target> 
<target name="dist" depends="compile"> 
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" /> 
    <manifest file="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"> 
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="test.jar"/> 
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>   
    </manifest> 
    <jar manifest="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" jarfile="${dist}/lib/test.jar" basedir="${build}"/> 
</target> 
<target name="clean" description="clean up"><delete dir="${build}"/><delete dir="${dist}"/></target> 
</project>
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.cfsware.osco.test; 
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 

    } 


}
```

Comment: From what I can see from your project structure you have `com.cfsware.osco.test` and not `com.cfsware.osco.fff`

Comment: You see to have **three**. Yes **three**. Different packages here. You directory structure suggests the package `com.cfsware.osco.test`; your `build.properties` suggests `com.cfsware.osco.ant`; and your class suggests `com.cfsware.osco.fff`. So which is it?

Comment: the inconsistensies in the naming are due to bad copy pasting, actual project attribute naming is consistent

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
```

It should be:

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.cfsware.osco.test.Main"/>
```

... in other words, the fully-qualified name of the class. Your Java file should be in a directory matching the package declaration, too.

Comment: then I get Error: Could not find or load main class com.cfsware.osco.test.Main

Comment: @aelgoa: Did the compile stage work properly? If you take out the manifest part, does your jar file build properly with everything you need? Why are you setting the `Class-Path` part of the manifest ?

Comment: yes compiling worked in every single case I tried. I copied the manifest code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10202654/1260792 and I've tried pre-existing files as well as build-time generation.

Comment: @aelgoa: And what about removing the manifest? Does that then include everything you need? I think the example you've copied from is unfortunate in its choice of Class-Path...

Comment: When I remove the Class-Path attribute, same error. When I don't include a manifest, the jar command gives `no main manifest attribute, in dist\lib\test.jar` error

Comment: @aelgoa: Right, so you have a jar file. Have you checked its contents?

Comment: yes, It contains `com\cfsware\osco\test\Main.class` and `META-INF\Manifest.inf`. When I run the class file, same error.

Comment: @aelgoa: How were you trying to run the class?

Comment: I've tried `java -cp . Main.class` and `java Main.class`

Comment: @aelgoa: Well neither of those would work, a) because you specify a class name, not a filename, and b) because you haven't included the package name, and c) because you haven't included the jar file in the classpath. If you're very new to Java, I suggest you learn the basics about launching applications *before* you start trying to create executable jar files.